# Why is shift-alt being mapped to meta?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Some background: I look after the key handling code in the [Kodi media centre software](http://kodi.tv/), and I've been trying to pin down an obscure bug reported by a user. They have a remote control that emulates a keyboard and for a particular button sends the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. The trouble is that the keypress Kodi receives is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

I've discovered this also happens when I press that key combination on the keyboard, and in fact any combination involving <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> does similar things. The common factor seems to be having <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed simultaneously.

I understand that the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key was a modifier key on an old keyboard that is no longer used, but that Ubuntu can be configured to generate <kbd>Meta</kbd> keypresses. I wonder if there is a setting somewhere in Ubuntu that is causing the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> combination to be sent to X clients as a <kbd>Meta</kbd> keypress.

This is with Ubuntu 14.04, and I get the same behaviour in the standard shell and when using the LXDE shell.

Please shout if I've missed out any vital info - I'm a Windows developer and am a bit out of my depth with unix. I haven't gone into the details of the system calls Kodi uses to receive the key presses as I suspect that's more suited to a development site. What I'm primarily interested in is some setting that is user tweakable that might be causing this behaviour.

Comment: @chicks: have [another look](http://askubuntu.com/posts/567731/revisions).

Comment: @Fabby: thanks. I thought about the `meta`s too, but I worried it might confuse some people.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this behavior by running the following remap command: `xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Alt_L"`. This defines <kbd>Alt</kbd> as simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and not <kbd>Meta</kbd> when shifted.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, the system sees <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, but if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, the system sees <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, so pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> first and <kbd>Shift</kbd> second can work around the problem.